# JQuery trigger wont work on generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few elements in 'append' tag something like this:

```
...<a href="?my-action=' + data[i].id + '&token=' + data[i].token + '" class="deactivate">'+...
```

I can run ajax on click with function something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.deactivate', function(e) {
...
```

And it works but i would like trigger this as well on ajax success similar as main document elements:

```
$('#field_id').trigger('click');
```

I tied already  `$('body.deactivate').trigger('click');` or `$('.deactivate').trigger('click');` is it possible?

Comment: @Eric trigger is working with document elements but not with dynamic from append

Comment: Do the trigger click in your ajax success function after you append the dynamic stuff.
success: function(data){ $('selector').trigger('click')}

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to append the elements? Are you sure they exist in the current document, do you see them in the DOM browser?

Comment: The selected elements must existed (already append in DOM) before trigger() function is called. Is it so in your code? Can you show more code?

Comment: This is my original function to generate html `  $('body').on('click', 'a.deactivate', function(e) {` and i need to execute this again on ajax success

Comment: Regarding your posted code, `$('.deactivate').trigger('click');` would work so your issue is somewhere else

Comment: Also i tried with $('a.deactivate').trigger('click'); and still wont work

Comment: @Klapsius kindly   check `$(document).ready(function(){})` in your javascript

Comment: @prasad nothing wrong because other functions works fine

Comment: are you sure your ajax call are success?

Comment: @prasad more then 100% because it trigger document element $('#id').trigger('click');

Comment: could you check console.log if there is any error.

Comment: Its clear. I can see how parameters flows via ajax but no errors

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by append tag, but I assume you inserted some HTML into your document after attaching the onclicks with jQuery. And there is the crucial part, after. You see when jQuery attaches a handler like this it only attaches it to the currently loaded elements, so if you load more data afterwards you will have to attach handlers to these separately.

A quick fix would be to just remove all handlers like the ones you want and re-attach it to everything every time you load more data, but this is inefficient and might cause other problems down the line.

Preferably you would make your code in such a way that you can attach handlers as you generate elements. This way you have more control over what handles what and you don't get in the situation where some elements have proper handlers and some don't.

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger click on the element once the element has been created in the DOM.

For example this would work:

```
$('.element').html('<button id="field_id">click</button>')
$('#field_id').trigger('click');
```

There is no way to trigger any events to elements which have not yet been created.

`.on()` works differently, it creates `eventListener` which will work even when elements are added to the DOM later.